# Neural Networks training on multiple cores

Tags: c++, multithreading, neural-network

Straight to the facts.

My Neural network is a classic feedforward backpropagation.
I have a historical dataset that consists of:

> time, temperature, humidity, pressure

I need to predict next values basing on historical data.

This dataset is about *10MB* large therefore training it on one core takes ages. I want to go multicore with the training, but i can't understand what happens with the training data for each core, and what exactly happens after cores finish working.

According to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation#Multithreaded_Backpropagation

> The training data is broken up into equally large batches for each of
>   the threads. Each thread executes the forward and backward
>   propagations. The weight and threshold deltas are summed for each of
>   the threads. At the end of each iteration all threads must pause
>   briefly for the weight and threshold deltas to be summed and applied
>   to the neural network.

1. '*Each thread executes forward and backward propagations*' - this means, each thread just trains itself with it's part of the dataset, right? How many iterations of the training per core ?
2. '*At the en dof each iteration all threads must pause briefly for the weight and threshold deltas to be summed and applied to neural network*' - What exactly does that mean? When cores finish training with their datasets, wha does the main program do?

Thanks for any input into this!

Comment: probably suits better programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Quick unrelated suggestion: if you really want to push this to the edge you can use what companies are using right now: parallel processing capabilities (i.e. massively parallel processors). You can write your own neural network on openCL or CUDA and have it trained quickly (well, quick enough with respect to the naive approach)

Comment: How many iterations per core? One. That answer is given as part of your second question: "at the end of _each_ iteration". After combining, do another iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete training by backpropagation is often not the thing one is really looking for, the reason being overfitting. In order to obtain a better generalization performance, approaches such as weight decay or early stopping are commonly used.

On this background, consider the following heuristic approach: Split the data in parts corresponding to the number of cores and set up a network for each core (each having the same topology). Train each network completely separated of the others (I would use some common parameters for the learning rate, etc.). You end up with a number of http://www.texify.com/img/%5Cnormalsize%5C%21N_%7B%5Ctext%7B%7D%7D.gif
 trained networks http://www.texify.com/img/%5Cnormalsize%5C%21f_i%28x%29.gif.

Next, you need a scheme to combine the results. Choose http://www.texify.com/img/%5Cnormalsize%5C%21F%28x%29%3D%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5EN%5C%2C%20%5Calpha_i%20f_i%28x%29.gif, then use least squares to adapt the parameters http://www.texify.com/img/%5Cnormalsize%5C%21%5Calpha_i.gif such that http://www.texify.com/img/%5Cnormalsize%5C%21%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5EM%20%5C%2C%20%5Cbig%28F%28x_j%29%20-%20y_j%5Cbig%29%5E2.gif is minimized. This involves a singular value decomposition which scales linearly in the number of measurements M and thus should be feasible on a single core. Note that this heuristic approach also bears some similiarities to the Extreme Learning Machine. Alternatively, and more easily, you can simply try to average the weights, see below.

Moreover, see these answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749890/multithreaded-backpropagation).

---

Regarding your questions:

1. As Kris noted it will usually be one iteration. However, in general it can be also a small number chosen by you. I would play around with choices roughly in between 1 and 20 here. Note that the above suggestion uses infinity, so to say, but then replaces the recombination step by something more appropriate.
2. This step simply does what it says: it sums up all weights and deltas (what exactly depends on your algoithm). Remember, what you aim for is a single trained network in the end, and one uses the splitted data for estimation of this.

To collect, often one does the following:

(i) In each thread, use your current (global) network weights for estimating the deltas by backpropagation. Then calculate new weights using these deltas.

(ii) Average these thread-local weights to obtain new global weights (alternatively, you can sum up the deltas, but this works only for a single bp iteration in the threads). Now start again with (i) in which you use the same newly calculated weights in each thread. Do this until you reach convergence.

This is a form of iterative optimization. Variations of this algorithm:

- Instead of using always the same split, use random splits at each iteration step (... or at each n-th iteration). Or, in the spirit of random forests, only use a subset.
- Play around with the number of iterations in a single thread (as mentioned in point 1. above).
- Rather than summing up the weights, use more advanced forms of recombination (maybe a weighting with respect to the thread-internal training-error, or some kind of least squares as above).
- ... plus many more choices as in each complex optimization ...

Comment: Thank you David, i'll have a try - all that sounds sensible.

Answer (score 0):

For multicore parallelization it makes no sense to think about splitting the training data over threads etc. If you implement that stuff on your own you will most likely end up with a parallelized implementation that is slower than the sequential implementation because you copy your data too often.

By the way, in the current state of the art, people usually use **mini-batch stochastic gradient descent** for optimization. The reason is that you can simply forward propagate and backpropagate mini-batches of samples in parallel but batch gradient descent is usually much slower than stochastic gradient descent.

So how do you parallelize the forward propagation and backpropagation? You don't have to create threads manually! You can simply write down the forward propagation with matrix operations and use a parallelized linear algebra library (e.g. [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)) or you can do the parallelization with OpenMP in C++ (see e.g. [OpenANN](https://github.com/OpenANN/OpenANN/blob/master/src/FullyConnected.cpp#L70)).

Today, leading edge libraries for ANNs don't do multicore parallelization (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477145/open-source-neural-network-library/11477815#11477815) for a list). You can use GPUs to parallelize matrix operations (e.g. with CUDA) which is orders of magnitude faster.