# how to calculate instance error in neural network

Tags: c#, neural-network

I have a neural network with two output nodes and I am writing back propagation algorithm for it in c#. and this is how I am calculating instance error

```
 instanceErr += (double)((Math.Pow(error1[0], 2) + Math.Pow(error1[1], 2)) / 2);
```

this code is inside a loop with executes for 224 time as I have 224 instances.Is this the right way to do it?
after that I calculate the error per epoch like this.

```
 meanSqrE = (double) (instanceErr/224);
```

but after the 2 epochs, it starts giving me same error  30 times and after that it prints this `NaN`. I have no idea where I go wrong

Comment: by 30 times I mean for next 30 epochs

Comment: NaN is an abbreviation for "Not a Number".  error1 or instanceErr may be null which is giving the error.

Comment: I know its Not a Number which come when we try to divide 0 by 0, but I don't have any such thing in the code

Comment: if error is less than 1, squaring a number gets smaller.  Than dividing a very small number by 2 will get the equivalent of 0/0.

Comment: Are you rolling your own neural network? There are plenty of open-source frameworks that have complete implementations of back-propagation, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477145/open-source-neural-network-library for some more information. I know it doesn't answer your question directly, but it may save you the headache of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @Clint actually it is a very complex topic and I tried to understand the codes written by others but I couldn't, therefore I had to start writing it from scratch. I even couldn't find any tutorials with the open source. can you suggest me any that I can use with c#? with the tutorial if possible?